# open ssrs report in an iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, reporting-services, ssl-certificate

I have developed a website which runs at SSL (https). I want to open some SSRS reports at the website in an iframe. But it is not opened since browsers say that "Blocked loading mixed active content" in the browser's console.If I hit report's URL in another tab or another browsers window then it opens.Also if I run my website at http only then browser opens the report in the iframe perfectly at the website.I think this problem is arises since website runs on https and report url is http only.
What can I do to resolve this issue without change in any of the URL.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no way for you to run SSRS on SSL?  Why can't you change that url?  Is that not allowed by your company or are you worried about buying another SSL certificate or something?

Comment: What browser(s) have you tried using?

Comment: Hi  Dan,Actually there is already a website that share the same report server and that website do not runs on SSL, so I think if I run SSRS on SSL then the website that share the same report server will stop the execution of the SSRS.

Comment: I tried this at Firefox,chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SSRS are you using?  It is possible to install multiple instances of SSRS on the same machine.  They may not have access to the same sets of reports, but I'm not sure if that would even be an issue for you.  The configuration you are attempting seems a bit messy.  Personally I would try to get all of the sites on SSL to be consistent, but that sounds like you may not be able to achieve that, politically.

Anyway, here's a link to get you started with the multiple SSRS instance approach, if you'd like to try it.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403426(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403426%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)